# Strategy pattern in a spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In a spring boot application, In one of my controller, I used a strategy pattern to feed some data.

```
@Component
public class SearchStrategy extends AbstractStrategy implements Strategy {

    //spring ui model
    private final Model model;

    public SearchStrategy(Model model) {
        super(model);
        this.model = model;
    }
    ..
}

public abstract class AbstractStrategy {

    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationContext ctx; //spring class

    public AbstractStrategy(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}

@Component
public class StrategyContext {

    private Strategy strategy;
    public void setStrategy(Strategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }
    ...
}
```

In my rest controller, I do

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String getStrategy(final Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ...
    StrategyContext sc = new StrategyContext();
    sc.setStrategy(new SearchStrategy(model));
    ...
}
```

Actually, I get

> org.springframework.ui.Model' that could not be found.

I should not use **new** but I don't know how to pass model.

Tried to put StrategyContext in autowired in my controller, but I need to pass model to the Strategy implementation and abstract class

Any idea to solve error, design tips?

---

**Edit**, complete error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.search.ui.SearchStrategy required a bean of type 'org.springframework.ui.Model' that could not be found.
```

Comment: Can you post the whole exception?

Comment: it's done, just don't know if there are a solution, cause i need model but just get it in the controller...

Comment: Model is only available in the controller, so you can't autowire it in your custom class. Nobody says you " should not use new" operator. **Dependency Injection != @Autowired**. In your AbstractStrategy class you are already applying Dependency Injection via constructor...

Comment: Ok but actually I don't use Autowired on model, I just use Autowired on ApplicationContect object in AbstractStrategy and I get  the constructor error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails on startup because there is no `Model` (yet, in given context - it will be created on web call). Remove `@Component` annotation. From the context you have shown us, there is no need for Spring to manage `SearchStrategy` for you. Controller method will work as expected - `Model` will be autocreated for you.

Comment: I removed @Component annotation in  StrategyContext class, get same error. I removed it also in SearchStrategy class, but now appContext attribute in AbstractStrategy is null; So I removed Autowired on ApplicationContext. In controller i put a Autowired on StrategyContext  and appContext. I do a new for my strategy object and pass to them a model an appContext. Maybe there is a better spring way ?

Comment: Default scope for managed beans is singleton. What you want to have, is to have request scoped beans (as you depends on view model and this is new for every request). But anyway, you can always autowire app context to controller and pass as additional constructor argument. It is obvious that app context is null, as only managed beans are able to have autowired dependencies (eg. in fields). Good entry point would be to add `ApplicationContext` as param to `AbstractStrategy` constructor

Answer (score 1):

The `Component` annotation should be removed from SearchStrategy class. As the SearchStrategy class doesn't contain default constructor, Spring tries to create the bean with object `Model` and failed to create the bean because `Model` is not defined as a bean either.

1) Please remove the `@Component` annotation from SearchStrategy and AbstractStrategy classes

2) You can keep the `@Component` annotation for StrategyContext class

3) Replace the new object creation with Autowired object. Please see the sample code below:-

```
@Autowired
private StrategyContext strategyContext;

@GetMapping("/strategy")
public String getStrategy(final Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println(model);

    /*StrategyContext sc = new StrategyContext();
    sc.setStrategy(new SearchStrategy(model));*/
    strategyContext.setStrategy(new SearchStrategy(model));

    System.out.println(strategyContext.getStrategy());

    return "Hello";
}
```

**Update:-**

In simple terms, remove Component annotation from all Strategy classes except StrategyContext. So, context should be able to create the required object and return it.

As soon as you remove Component annotation, the `autowired` wouldn't work. In other words, you will get `null` for ApplicationContext. So, you should not define `ApplicationContext` as well (i.e. remove it from AbstractStrategy).

All object creation logic should go into context class. Context is the only Spring managed class. All other classes are just normal Java class (i.e. not Spring beans).

Comment: ApplicationContext need to be pass also to the class

Comment: You can remove the Component annotation and protected ApplicationContext ctx from AbstractStrategy. I don't know why you have declared the ApplicationContext in AbstractStrategy. Not sure whether you are going to add more logic in AbstractStrategy.

Comment: Need there ApplicationContext because I have method to do some treatment... otherwise it's sure that should be useless

Comment: `strategyContext.setStrategy(new SearchStrategy(model));`
I don't think this is the right approach if `strategyContext ` is a singleton or prototype-scoped bean. What would happen if:

```
@Autowired
private StrategyContext strategyContext;
```
is injected in another class and being used while a the app also process a `/strategy` request?

Comment: @ootero Yes, agreed. I have just given the sample code. The context class should be stateless and should create the object based on the model.